# Curve parameterization trick

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So, I was given this really *nasty* problem to solve

> Suppose C is parametrized by
>   $\mathbf{g}(t) = \left[\begin{array}{c}e^{t^{3}\cos\!\left(2\pi t^{25}\right)}\cr
> t^{6}+3t^{3}+3\cr
> e^{\sin\!\left(3t\right)}\!\left(t^{3}-t\right)\cr\end{array}\right] \ , \quad 0\le t\le 1 \ .$
>
> Let $\omega = \left(6xz+y^{2}\right)\,dx + \left(2xy+3ze^{3yz}+3\right)\,dy + \left(3x^{2}+3ye^{3yz}+25z^{24}\right)\,dz$.

and I'm asked to find $\displaystyle\int_{C}\omega$

I started out setting it up like all of the similar parameterization problems, namely $\int_{a}^{b} x\frac{dx}{dt} + y\frac{dy}{dt} + z\frac{dz}{dt}$, where $x = e^{t^3cos(2\pi t^{25})}$, etc. but this gets *really ugly really quickly*.

Is there some trick that I'm missing to make this a lot less ugly, or is it just one big plug and chug?

Comment: This doesn't help you, but I just wanted to see what the curve looked like. http://i.stack.imgur.com/HDr63.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing something big indeed. They very likely gave you that question after teaching you about conservative fields.

I haven't checked,  but I'm willing to bet that the field above is conservative.

Comment: And thank goodness that it is!